# llvm irbuilder call instruction throwing exception on function inlining pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm new to LLVM. I am using the clang c++ API to compile multiple stub files (in c) to IR, and then stick them together using IR builder (after linking them) to eventually run via JIT.

All this works great, unless I add a functionInlining pass to my optimizations, at which point one of these function calls made in IR builder will trigger the following exception when the pass manager is run:

```
Assertion failed: (New->getType() == getType() && "replaceAllUses of value with new value of different type!"), function replaceAllUsesWith, file /Users/mike/Development/llvm/llvm/lib/IR/Value.cpp, line 356.
```

This is how I make the call instruction (pretty straight forward):

```
Function *kernelFunc = mModule->getFunction( (kernel->Name() + StringRef("_") + StringRef(funcName)).str());
if (kernelFunc){
    CallInst* newInst = builder.CreateCall(kernelFunc, args);
}
```

Later the module is optimized:

```
legacy::PassManager passMan;
PassManagerBuilder Builder;
Builder.OptLevel = 3;
//Builder.Inliner = llvm::createFunctionInliningPass(); //commenting this back in trigger the exception
Builder.populateModulePassManager(passMan);

passMan.run( *mModule ); //exception occurs before this call returns
```

Any ideas what to look for?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I finally setup my dev environment so I could inspect the assertion call in the debugger. I turns out the basic block being replaced had a different context set than the one it was being replaced with. going back and making sure IRBuilder was using the same context as the IR parsers solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try running llvm::verifyModule on your module to see if it's correct. You might have an error and have been getting lucky beforehand but it tripped something up in the inliner.

In general assertions check a subset of things that can be wrong with your module but verify checks a lot more.

It could be a bug in LLVM but more than likely it's a bad module, it's easy to happen.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't known about the verifyModule. Unfortunately, this module passes the verifier with no errors, and still throws in the inlining pass.